# Android Sharedpreferences and array

Tags: android, arrays, sharedpreferences

I created a weather widget. I store its configuration in `SharedPreferences`. The widget is updated by a service. I keep the weather information together with forecasts in an array. After the phone is off for the night i find that the array values are gone, maybe the system suspended? the service. Is there a way to store the array in `SharePreferences` so it is more sticky.

Comment: Regardless of the API level, Check http://sherifandroid.blogspot.com/2012/05/string-arrays-and-object-arrays-in.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure - either come up with a way to serialize/deserialize your object from a String that you can store in a SharedPreference (if it's a simple array of numbers, for instance, just making a quick split/join on commas might do it; basic [JSON serialization](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html)/deserialization might work for slightly more complex data), or use standard [Java serialization](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/) to turn your object into a bytestream and [save the data to a File](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) that you can read when needed. If you're really working with a lot of structured data, though, seriously consider using Android's excellent built-in support for SQLite, although that's a little more work.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I don't know the serialization, but was wondering, because is an array of strings, to iterate through the array and put each element as a pair in the SharedPreferences. So I could use for(i=0;i<wf.length;i++) {edit.putString("wf"+i,1);} Is that acceptable?

Comment: Sure, though possibly more work than just splitting a String because you'd also have to iterate back through all your sharedPreferences for deserialization.

Comment: Yes, it would be more work, any example on the web to serialize an array of strings and then back again? Thanks for all the info.

Comment: Why do you think "structured data" should be stroed in sqlite? Sqlite (and relational db iin general) are meant to keep relational data - not structured data. I'd say that structured data are exactly opposite of relational data.