# How to store String[] in android?

Tags: java, android

I want to store an array of strings internal in android but I want to do that in a separate class, not inactivity. How can I do that? And then retrieve it?

thanks

how I want to work whit it.I have 2 methods `addFoo(String s){}` and `String[] GetAllFoo(){}`
Inactivity I need to add some strings and get the whole array

Comment: What do you mean? You can specify string arrays in e.g. arrays.xml under /res/values

Comment: can you please give me a link where i can read how can i do that?

Comment: http://www.anddev.org/tinytut_-_arrays_as_xml-resources-t112.html

Comment: and can i add some data to this arrays.xml programaticaly or i need to open it and with serializer?thanks

Comment: Ah, no, then it isn't correct for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this thread explains how you should solve your problem
[Android Sharepreferences and array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864787/android-sharepreferences-and-array)

Answer (score 0):

Declare an inheritance  class entends Application, and then registered in Mainifest.xml. In the inheritance  class define your array.