# What's the method for storing arrays or custom objects (persistent data)?

Tags: android, persistent-storage

Is there any way to store a custom data object as persistent data without employing SQLite in Android?

I have a 3*3 matrix of EditText fields on screen, and I want to store all the content of those 9 fields into one "profile" (object). Other profiles can be created to have a different matrix with different data.

I thought of XML, but I would like to hear other opinions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could serialize the array and store it to the shared preferences, similar to the answer to this question:

[Android Sharepreferences and array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864787/android-sharepreferences-and-array)

To store multiple profiles you could possibly store each in the shared preferences with a key like "Profile-1", "Profile-2", etc.  You could then have another shared preference that has the number of Profiles you have.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. I didn't see that question/answer. I like how that looks like, but what about dynamic number of profiles?
EDIT: eg: create 5 profiles (each with their 3*3 matrix object) I know that it could work if I serialize the object if it's just one profile. What about multiple? Thanks again.

Comment: i added some more info.  If you have a dynamic number of profiles you might want to consider using sqlite.  Surely you'll come to a point where you'll want to store more data and sqlite will be the best option.

Comment: yeah problably, thanks a lot... I marked yours as the answer
I think I'll try to serialize/deserialize all the profile info in one field per profile in the sqlite db, i think that'll work better.

Comment: @Armando How did this work out? Did you use SQL for saving your instance state as well?

Comment: @Deco I used SQLite for storing those 9 objects (serializing their properties into a string) but that's far from appropriate. I decided to use SimpleXML instead from now on, simple xml api that works great. It does the whole job. Translates an object to an xml-structured one, check the website [link](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) - it has good list of tutorials

Comment: @Armando I've heard serialization is quite resource intensive. Would SQLite be better if all my objects properties are mere ints and I can avoid serialization?

Comment: @Deco The reason I used xml serialization is that I might handle different number of classes inside a class. And since I want to have the chance of backing that up via web, the xml seemed to be the right choice. As for your case, yes you can. If you are only interested in backing your instance state, check the documentation on how to manage SQLite databases(bit more complex but has potential for bigger schemas), and Shared Preferences (easier), in Android. Good luck, and if you have any doubts/problems just let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like

```
public bool save(SaveableObject s, Context context, String fileName)
{
    try
    {
        FileOutputStream fos;
        ObjectOutputStream os;
        File file1 = context.getExternalFilesDir(null);
        File file2 = new File(file1, fileName);
        fileName = file2.getAbsolutePath();
        fos = context.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        os.writeObject((Object)analysis);
        os.close();
        fos.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

which should save a file to `/sdcard/fileName`.

Answer (score 1):

Your options are explained in the [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) topic of the docs.

Comment: Thank you. I checked on that but some how I feel I'm between those options. SharedPref seems kinda simple but a sqlite db is kinda complex for what I need. I will use SQLite if there's no other way around.. thanks!